# How can I find the version of Docker I am using?

Tags: docker

As the title says, how can one find Docker's version?

Answer (score 2):

For the daemon's version (meaning the engine's version) that's running on your server:

```
$ dockerd --version
Docker version 20.10.2, build 8891c58
```

For your client's version that's running on your local computer and with which you send commands to the daemon on the remote server:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
```